# Loop for Ruby | Selenium | Web Testing

Tags: ruby, selenium, testing, web-applications, automation

I'm trying to write some ruby to perform the following:

I'm testing a web page which has a form, a search button, and a search results underneath.

When I enter an invoice number into the form e.g. 123456 and I click the "Search" button, if the Invoice has been successfully saved , then it will show up under the  "Search Results" section, and if not, then it will say "No results found". Sometimes it takes a few seconds for the database to  finish processing an invoice so I would like to make a loop that keeps pressing the search button every few seconds until the invoice is found, and once the condition is met, then do something else.

Comment: Search for a Text and until the Text you look found retry(loop) the action. 
If the Text found exit from the loop. share your work around that help us to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up a `while` loop that breaks once a WebElement meeting certain criteria has been located.

```
# Keep track of whether or not invoice has been found
found = false

# First, attempt to locate the desired invoice
begin
    # click the search button
    driver.find_element(:name, "search_button").click

    # check if invoice exists, set found to true if it does
    expect(driver.find_element(some_locator_here).displayed?).to eql true
    found = true

rescue Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError
    # catch NoSuchElementError if invoice does not exist, leave found as false
    puts("Element not found")

# if invoice is not found, continue trying to find it in a loop
while found == false do
    begin
        # click the search button
        driver.find_element(:name, "search_button").click

        # attempt to locate the invoice
        expect(driver.find_element(some_locator_here).displayed?).to eql true
        found = true

    rescue Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError
        puts("Element not found")
```

This will click the search button and attempt to locate the desired invoice in a loop, then catch the `NoSuchElementError` if the desired invoice does not exist. You will need to replace `some_locator_here` with something like `:name, "invoice_name"` so that you can locate your invoice and determine whether or not it has been found. Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: Thank you so much. This has definitely helped me go in the right direction!